# Faster finding of all cubic numbers

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

I want to improve the performance of this program.

```
count = 0
store = []
n = 9238899039
for i in range(1,n):
    if i*i*i <= n:
        count += 1
        store.append(i)
print count
```

At the moment it is very slow. I need to find all cubic numbers up to n.

Comment: Uhmm wait, _`store.append(i)`_ did you actually mean to store `store.append(i*i*i)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop keeps running for a whole lot of numbers (values of `i`), that will always have a bigger cubic result than `n`. This gives you a significant performance hit.

You can simply add a `break` statement as soon the condition `if i*i*i <= n:` is no longer fulfilled.

This will prevent to process any further values of `i`, which will also certainly not fulfill the condition.

```
for i in range(1,n):
    if i*i*i <= n:
        count += 1
        store.append(i)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You could also find the cube root of `n` and make the loop go up to that, instead of to `n` itself.

Comment: @Blckknght Sure, but that won't make much difference besides the extra effort (performance cost) of calculating the cubic root of `n`. Using the `break` the last `i` processed actually is the cubic root of `n`, thus my solution is even a few ticks faster performance wise.

Comment: @Blckknght Also note that the cubic root of `n` (2,098.328151) isn't a plain integer value.

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason to use brute force like that.  I couldn't even get the program to complete without crashing.

To find the `count`, just take the cube root of `n`, and round down.  Then, it's a simple matter to construct the list you need.

```
n = 9238899039
count = int(n ** (1.0/3))
store = range(1, count + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A classic performance improvement in calculating a series of numbers is to take advantage of previous work.

If the cube of `X` is `Y`, then the cube of `X+1` is `Y + 3*X*(X+1) + 1`.

With such a simple function of `Y=X*X*X`, I doubt it will be faster than [List numbers 1 to cuberoot(n)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115153/29485), but the idea is useful in a general sense.

Below is a C code that hopefully expresses the idea clear enough for a `python` user.

```
void cubes(unsigned long limit) {
  unsigned i = 1;
  unsigned long cube = 1;
  while (cube <= limit) {
    printf("%u %lu\n", i, cube);
    cube += 3L*i*(i + 1) + 1;
    i++;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  cubes(9238899039);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 1
2 8
3 27
...
2096 9208180736
2097 9221366673
2098 9234565192
```

---

Another math solution takes advantage of differences of differences.  No multiplication needed.

```
void cubes(unsigned long limit) {
  unsigned i = 1;
  unsigned d1 = 0;
  unsigned long d2 = 1;
  unsigned long cube = 1;
  while (cube <= limit) {
    printf("%u %lu\n", i, cube);
    d1 += 6;
    d2 += d1;
    cube += d2;
    i++;
  }
}
```